# Closing the ZXing scanner through Android Coding

Tags: android

I am using the ZXing scanner, this code is running the scanner, but if I want to close it using android coding, how do I do it?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: If you are using Activity based ZXing library, probably it is not possible to close that activity using code. You need to either press "back" button to close that activity or barcode scanning successfully done. If you want zxing library integration in your application without activity, i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting the intent using startActivityForResult(), once the scan is complete it should call back to onActivityResult() method , something along these lines:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {       
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          //unpack the intent for the result example:
          intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
     } 
}
```

Comment: He knows about this. What he is asking is how can he close that activity using code in his application?